# How can I further identify and fix network speed slowdown on home LAN?

Tags: networking, performance, bandwidth, iperf

I have been trying to troubleshoot a home LAN throughput issue. I have an Asus router with two boxes, a Windows 11 PC and an Unraid Linux server, connected directly with cat6 cables to 1Gb ports. The Linux box has a 802.3ad link-bonded pair (verified configured correctly). The router supports a few other devices through eth and wifi.

I'm trying to figure out why my throughput from the PC to the server experiences intermittent degradation. This is affecting file transfer times between SSDs on both machines, but the problem shows up when measuring throughput without getting disks involved.

I generally expect to maintain a consistent average line speed of at least 850 Mbits/sec.

Here's an example of what happens using iperf3 to measure when the PC sends and the server receives:

```
C:\...\Downloads>iperf3.exe -c 192.168.50.100 -n 2000M -bidir
Connecting to host 192.168.50.100, port 5201
[  4] local 192.168.50.200 port 59322 connected to 192.168.50.100 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-1.01   sec  26.6 MBytes   222 Mbits/sec
[  4]   1.01-2.00   sec  27.6 MBytes   233 Mbits/sec
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec   103 MBytes   864 Mbits/sec
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec   106 MBytes   886 Mbits/sec
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec   105 MBytes   883 Mbits/sec
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec   103 MBytes   864 Mbits/sec
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec   105 MBytes   885 Mbits/sec
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec   102 MBytes   858 Mbits/sec
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec   106 MBytes   887 Mbits/sec
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec  55.2 MBytes   463 Mbits/sec
[  4]  10.00-11.00  sec  66.8 MBytes   560 Mbits/sec
[  4]  11.00-12.00  sec  59.6 MBytes   500 Mbits/sec
[  4]  12.00-13.00  sec  52.4 MBytes   438 Mbits/sec
[  4]  13.00-14.00  sec  67.8 MBytes   571 Mbits/sec
[  4]  14.00-15.00  sec  28.5 MBytes   239 Mbits/sec
[  4]  15.00-16.00  sec  48.5 MBytes   407 Mbits/sec
[  4]  16.00-17.01  sec  50.8 MBytes   420 Mbits/sec
[  4]  17.01-18.00  sec  92.0 MBytes   782 Mbits/sec
[  4]  18.00-19.00  sec   106 MBytes   888 Mbits/sec
[  4]  19.00-20.00  sec   108 MBytes   906 Mbits/sec
[  4]  20.00-21.00  sec   100 MBytes   843 Mbits/sec
[  4]  21.00-22.01  sec   102 MBytes   855 Mbits/sec
[  4]  22.01-23.00  sec   105 MBytes   887 Mbits/sec
[  4]  23.00-24.00  sec   109 MBytes   913 Mbits/sec
[  4]  24.00-24.60  sec  63.2 MBytes   883 Mbits/sec
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-24.60  sec  1.95 GBytes   682 Mbits/sec  sender
[  4]   0.00-24.60  sec  1.95 GBytes   682 Mbits/sec  receiver
```

These slowdowns occur regularly, sometimes lasting over a minute.
When I flip this around and send from the server to the PC, the lag disappears:

```
C:\...\Downloads>iperf3.exe -c 192.168.50.100 -n 2000M -bidir -R
Connecting to host 192.168.50.100, port 5201
Reverse mode, remote host 192.168.50.100 is sending
[  4] local 192.168.50.200 port 58040 connected to 192.168.50.100 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec   110 MBytes   922 Mbits/sec
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec   107 MBytes   900 Mbits/sec
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec   104 MBytes   874 Mbits/sec
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec   108 MBytes   908 Mbits/sec
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec   107 MBytes   900 Mbits/sec
[  4]   5.00-6.01   sec  95.7 MBytes   798 Mbits/sec
[  4]   6.01-7.00   sec   103 MBytes   870 Mbits/sec
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec   106 MBytes   892 Mbits/sec
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec   105 MBytes   881 Mbits/sec
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec   108 MBytes   907 Mbits/sec
[  4]  10.00-11.00  sec   104 MBytes   871 Mbits/sec
[  4]  11.00-12.00  sec   107 MBytes   897 Mbits/sec
[  4]  12.00-13.00  sec   103 MBytes   863 Mbits/sec
[  4]  13.00-14.00  sec   105 MBytes   880 Mbits/sec
[  4]  14.00-15.00  sec   107 MBytes   901 Mbits/sec
[  4]  15.00-16.00  sec   102 MBytes   854 Mbits/sec
[  4]  16.00-17.00  sec   105 MBytes   882 Mbits/sec
[  4]  17.00-18.00  sec   108 MBytes   910 Mbits/sec
[  4]  18.00-18.96  sec   103 MBytes   908 Mbits/sec
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr
[  4]   0.00-18.96  sec  1.95 GBytes   885 Mbits/sec    2   sender
[  4]   0.00-18.96  sec  1.95 GBytes   885 Mbits/sec        receiver
```

(The same speed transfers happen when I run the test with the PC as the iperf3 server and the Linux box as the client.)

I've been troubleshooting various scenarios and have already tried:

- ensuring no other devices are actively transferring data to the server at the same time (with and without pair bonding turned on)
- changing cables
- different router eth ports (all are 1Gb)
- rebooting my router

Anyone with networking experience have some suggestions for what else to try in isolating the issue?

Comment: The problem looks to be on the windows PC side. Something i always try and do is boot from a linux live environment and see if the problem persists. If it doesnt, it's likely some driver issue.

Comment: Thank you! I did as you said with a bootable Ubuntu USB and ran the iperf test again. The PC kept a rock-solid 941 Mbits/sec connection. So yes, the problem is definitely on the Win 11 side. Either a driver issue or a process periodically consuming bandwidth. Now I know where to keep looking.